# TVP5150 output 0x80,0x10 and input video signal not locked

Tags: analog, camera, video, decoder

This is my first question, I hope everything is ok :)

I have been struggling with a problem for a while now. I have a PAL camera (from which I barely have any information) connected to a TVP5150AM1 IC but I only get a repeated sequence of 128 bytes with 0x80 and 0x10 values followed by a lot of 0x00 bytes in the output frame buffer.

For what I've searched online, this problem seems to appear because input video is not locking correctly. I know that because I'm reading the 88h register (Status Register #1 in TVP5150 datasheet) of the TVP5150 and obtaining 0's in Bit 0, 1 and 2 (Color, Horizontal and Vertical Locks).

Also, I tested with an oscilloscope the pin 1 of TVP5150 (AIP1A) and seems like the input signal is reaching there. The input signal schematic is the same as the one in TVP5150's datasheet.

The resolution I'm setting is 720x576 at a 25 frame rate. My TVP5150's configuration is basically the following:

```
-Register 0x00: 0x00 (AIP1A selected)
-Register 0x03: 0x6F
-Register 0x0D: 0x47
-Register 0x0F: 0x02
```

How can I get input video signal finally locked?

It would be great if someone could help me on this as soon as possible.

Thanks for your time and have a great day :)

Best Regards,

Iago Loureiro.